# How can I use powershell to change sid in csv to user?

Tags: powershell, csv

This seems basic however can't find or figure out anywhere.

I have a .csv file that I would like to import, change the user column that has different SIDs to the user name that corresponds, then export back to the .csv. I know how to find the SIDtoUser, but I can't figure out how to do the replace in the .csv. Also some user columns are blank or have "admin" which I need to leave alone.

Current

```
ComputerName,   TimeStamp,  Message,    User               
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message1,   admin  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message2  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message3,   S-1-5-21...1105  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message4,   S-1-5-21...1255
```

Would like it to read

```
ComputerName,   TimeStamp,  Message,    User  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message1,   admin  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message2  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message3,   user1  
hp8440,         8/30/2012,  message4,   user2
```

Comment: when entering data or code you should select the data or code section then click the {} button on the toolbar.  This will auto-format your data/code.

Comment: Thank you for the info this was my first post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Import-Csv .\sid.csv | ForEach-Object{

    if($_.User -and $_.User -ne 'admin')
    {
        # User is not empty and not admin
        # perform translation and assign the results back to the User column
        # then return the current object back to the pipeline
        $_.User = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.User).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
        $_
    }
    else
    {
        # Ignore empty User or admin 
        # and return the current object back to the pipeline
        $_
    }

} | Export-Csv .\users.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

As a one-liner:

```
Import-Csv .\data.csv |%{ $_.User = ConvertSidToUserName $_.User; $_ } | Export-Csv .\updated.csv
```

A bit more readable...

```
$data = Import-Csv .\data.csv

# replace the User Propery
$data |%{ $_.User = ConvertSidToUserName $_.User }

# export back out to csv
$data | Export-Csv .\updated.csv
```

Comment: Still pretty new to the powershell game, but I'm guessing the ConvertSidtoUserName is refering to a function that I would add in my script to convert the Sid correct?

Comment: Yes.  From your original question it sounded like you already had code to do that part.