# Script to convert multiple SID to readable username

Tags: powershell, vbscript

I have a text file that contain below detail, so I need help on the script that can convert multiple SID to the readble username, but I'm really doubt with the coding.

**Window based permission file contain information as below sample when open with notepad**

```
    [/]      
    S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-12231=rw  
    S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-15527=rw  

    [AM_ATTG:/]     
    S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-1207=rw
```

Between, I have found the script to convert SID from [How can I use powershell to change sid in csv to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200189/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-change-sid-in-csv-to-user)

Therefore, I save the file into .csv and put heading for **first column as User** and **second column as Permission**

```
    User                                             Permission
    [/]      
    S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-12231    rw  
    S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-15527    rw  

    [AM_ATTG:/]     
    S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-1207     rw
```

but I getting the error below when tried the first powershell script, your reply on any hints about my post is very much appreciated.

```
Import-Csv : Cannot process argument because the value of argument "name" is invalid. Change the value of the "name" argument and run the operation again.  
At line:1 char:19
+Import-Csv <<<<  .\sid.csv | ForEach-Object{
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Import-Csv], PSArgumentException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Argument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportCsvCommand
```

Comment: Remove the ending ' rw' foreach SID value in your .csv file.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you make the csv file look like that (comma delimited):

```
Sid,Permission
S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-12231,rw  
S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-15527,rw   
S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-1207,rw
```

Then you can do:

```
Import-Csv SID.csv | 
Select-Object Sid,Permission,@{n='User';e={(New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.Sid).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value}}
```

Comment: I have tried both removing the column permission and remove at run time but nothing happen, no error display while execute via powershell too.

Comment: my post may not clear but I have tried both removing the column that indicate permission or removing them at run time but nothing happen, no error display while execute via powershell too. the original .csv save into 2 column as below <table><tr><td>user</td><td>Permission</td></tr><tr><td>S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-15527</td><td>rw</td></tr></table>

Comment: Put just the SID values in a csv file under a AccessPathName header and try my example. Your example shows the usage of CSV and the last comment shows HTML tags.

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I have 2000++ SID to be converted, the file was originally in the text format that contain information as above (AccessPathName, i put to represent the repositories path that the user in SID format has access, after = is the permission level). I've saved above file into .csv and change the column header for SID to AccessPathName as your comment but still nothing after run your script, the script import .csv file and how the outcome will be? can it export output in .csv file with the readable username replace at the SID column?

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample CSV content? It would greatly help me and others help you.

Comment: I need 15 reputation to post the image, really sorry. the file originally is a Windows-based permission file on VisualSVN that contain Reposipotories path, follow with the list of Username (SID format) who has access to that repositories and his permission level. sample show as above if I save it to .csv i need to filter Z to A as in the 1st column it contains the Repositories path and the SID, then assign the column name. the 2nd column is associate permission level e.g rw, r, ..

Comment: Just post it as text, the header line and two lines of data. That way we can get sense of it.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript flavor:

```
sidList = Array( "S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-12231=rw" _
  , "S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-15527=rw" _
  , "S-1-5-21-1449722967-1661817991-10773629-1207=rw" _
)

Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

For Each sid In sidList
  Set obj = wmi.Get("Win32_SID.SID='" & Replace(sid, "=rw", "") & "'")
  WScript.Echo obj.ReferencedDomainName & "\" & obj.AccountName
Next
```

**Update:** You could implement the script as a filter like this:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

Do Until WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
  line = Trim(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine)
  If UCase(Left(line, 2)) = "S-" Then
    Set obj = wmi.Get("Win32_SID.SID='" & Replace(sid, "=rw", "") & "'")
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine obj.ReferencedDomainName & "\" & obj.AccountName
  End If
Loop
```

Run the filter like this:

```
type input.txt | cscript //NoLogo filter.vbs > output.txt
```

Note that you must use `cscript.exe` or you wont have access to `WScript.StdIn` or `WScript.StdOut`.

Comment: actually I prefer VBscript, however I have 2000++ SID to be converted, the file was originally in the text format that contain information as above (AccessPathName represent the repositories path that the user in SID format has access, after = is the permission level),would it be easier to save in .csv for the conversion?

Comment: I run this command: **type input.txt | cscript // vb3.vbs > output.txt** but i get the empty output as  Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

\
\
\
\
\
\
\
\

Comment: The SIDs are not known on the local computer or in the computer's domain.