# Powershell replace sid in csv with username

Tags: powershell, csv, sid

I have a csv or txt with workstation names and some sids from registry. I want to replace the sids with user names in the original csv. The sids have a ":" at the end and a letter after that, that's why I use split.
I tried also "[text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12200189/how-can-i-use-powershell-to-change-sid-in-csv-to-user) but is not working for me. TIA

```
$sids = Import-csv "C:\temp\sids2.csv" 
foreach($sid in $sids){
if ($sid.'ColumnName' -like "*S-1-5*"){
$ssid = $sid.'ColumnName'.split(":")[0]
$name = ((New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($ssid)).Translate( [System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])).Value
$ssid.Replace("$ssid","$name")}
}
```

It doesn't change the csv file.

Same for:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\sids2.csv" | ForEach-Object{

    if($_.sid -and $_.sid -like "*S-1-5*")
    {
        # User is not empty and not admin
        # perform translation and assign the results back to the User column
        # then return the current object back to the pipeline
        $_.sid = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $_.sid).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
        $_
    }
    else
    {
        # Ignore empty User or admin 
        # and return the current object back to the pipeline
        $_
    }

} | Export-Csv c:\temp\users.csv
```

The new csv is same as source csv.

csv example:

```
ws,date,time,sid,sid1,sid2,sid3,sid4  
WSxxx,13/03/2024,14:36:00,S-1-5-**-*******-*******-****:d,admin:f,,,  
WSzzz,13/03/2024,14:48:00,admin:f,%S-1-5-**-*******-*******-****:d,%S-1-5-**-***:d,,,
```

Comment: Can you post an example of the input CSV?

Comment: Looks like the column is named `User`, not `sid` or even `ColumnName`, so why aren't you using the actual column name??

Comment: Simply take your second code and replace all `$_.sid` into `$_.User` (also, append ` -NoTypeInformation` to the Export-Csv command)

Comment: Thanks Theo. The column name is "sid" and I want to replace the sid value with the name of the user in the same cell. The column will continue named sid, that's ok at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
$all = Import-csv "c:\temp\sid.csv"

 foreach($a in $all){
 if ($a.sid -and $a.sid -like "*S-1-5*"){
 $aa = $a.sid.split(":")[0]
 $a.sid = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier ($aa)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
 }
 $all | export-csv "c:\temp\sid.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
 }
```